# How do we create a list of files which have changed since the last deployment? Using Git

Tags: git, deployment, tfs

We are using TFS to deploy PDF files from a Git repository.

Deployments are tied to a specific branch.

Every so often it is decided that the branch contains good enough files to deploy.

We only want to deploy the files which have changed since the last deploy, not the entire branch. It is huge and takes too long to deploy the whole thing.

How can we tag the branch in a certain way when deployments happen and then when the next deployment is desired, compare the current branch to the tag and then deploy only the changes / differences / deltas?

Just to emphasize, this branch only contains PDF files, not code. It does not need to be compiled.

TO CLARIFY:

On the build server, we want to avoid having to clone the entire repository every time the deployment process runs. Usually, the first step in the deploy is to clone the repository, but this is taking too long. Is there a way to only pull down the files which have been added or modified? Sparse checkout perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

All the answer is in your question:

1. each time you want to deploy, you create a tag: `git tag X.Y.Z ${COMMIT_TO_TAG}`
2. to compare with previous tag by listing just files: `git diff --name-status ${PREVIOUS_TAG}..${TAG_TO_DEPLOY}`

To find the previous tag:

- before creating the current tag: `git describe --first-parent --tags --abbrev=0 ${COMMIT_TO_TAG}`
- after creating the current tag: `git describe --first-parent --tags --abbrev=0 ${TAG_TO_DEPLOY}~1`

Comment: How will the build script know what the current commit is to create the tag?

How will the build script know what the previous deployment tag was?

Comment: "Every so often it is decided that the branch contains good enough files to deploy." ==> YOU decide that you have to tag. Maybe then by adding an option to the build script.

Comment: To clarify, @zigarn, 

On the build server, we want to avoid having to clone the entire repository every time the deployment process runs. Usually, the first step in the deploy is to clone the repository, but this is taking too long. Is there a way to only pull down the files which have been added or modified? Sparse checkout perhaps?

Comment: Can't you just keep the same clone then simply fetch and checkout? Else sparse checkout or shallow clone could be solutions.

Comment: I personally think it should be ok to keep the same clone on the machine. I will try for that solution. Do you know anything about the other options you mentioned and whether they could be used to pull down only the files which have changed since a specified commit / tag?

Comment: In my mind I am imagining that perhaps I can clone the git database without actually pulling the files down (clone --bare?) and then somehow run the commands you mentioned to determine the changes, and then somehow use some other command to copy down only the changed files. Am I on the right track @zigarn?

Comment: When you clone a repository you get all the versions of all the files: compared to clone, checkout is a very light command. The purpose of 'git fetch' is to get only the modifications since last fetch/clone.